# Is there a single word for date of death?

Tags: single-word-requests

Since we have a single word like *birthday*, is there a corresponding term for the date of someone’s death?

Comment: I don't think so, birthdays are celebratory. Clearly the opposite is not. Finally, I am reminded of a [short story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life-Line).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch "the opposite is not"? It depends on who died: witness some of the celebratory reactions to [Margaret Thatcher's death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_funeral_of_Margaret_Thatcher#Other_domestic_reactions)

Comment: @Senex Perhaps I should have said,  clearly no one hopes their death is celebrated. I know I don't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I think they call it "commemoration" when people who liked you mark the day of your death ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I believe those are usually somber. Also clearly Senex found a good answer.

Comment: There isn't really a single word. But there **is** a single character. If you want to write the death year of someone named Joe Black, you could just write _Joe Black ✝1995_, using any of several typographic cross symbols (this one happens to be **✝**, Unicode `2710D Latin Cross`).

Comment: @JohnLawler, just out of curiosity, do you use that with non-Christians too? I would imagine they (or more likely their survivors) would be annoyed.

Comment: I'm not sure. It might not be in order in some cases. As usual with strange typography, inquire locally.

Comment: I don't know why non-Christians would be annoyed. They are not annoyed with gravestones I'd hope, which is more of what the latin cross character is symbolizing rather than any kind of religious meaning. If they are annoyed by it, they are looking for reasons to be annoyed.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I like that a lot.  But I thought symbols were off-topic concerning English usage?

Comment: I would be _most_ displeased with a cross on my gravestone. I'm rather sorry that it's the standard symbol in genealogy, and if someone can suggest another I'll adopt it.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - With a name like that I wouldn’t think you’d need one.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one has mentioned it, but there's also "yearday", in addition to "deathday". Apart from that, no other words though. And they're both relative neologisms.

Comment: @JohnLawler The correct Unicode code point is `U+271d`; there is no zero there. Further, a symbol with just as long history for marking the date of death, is the dagger: `U+2020`. It is also known as obelisk and obelus, and has the advantage of being non-religious (despite similarity).

Comment: @AndrewLazarus It is not the standard symbol, as per my comment above; the standard symbol is to the best of my knowledge the dagger.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus How about ⛧?

Answer (score 10):

I think the closest word is *obit*, which the Oxford English Dictionary defines as "A record or notice of a person's death, or of the date of it; (also, occas.) the date itself" (sense 1(b)), and further as "An office or service, usually a mass, held to pray for the soul of or otherwise commemorate a deceased person ... on the anniversary of his or her death, or at some other appointed time; a yearly or other regular memorial service" (sense 2(a)).

The second definition, referring to a yearly commemoration, shows that "obit" is a reasonably good analogue for death of "birthday" for birth.

EDIT: The OED also gives *obit day*, which might be a closer analogue (yes, it's not a single word...). An example quotation from the OED, dated 1995, is: "The communar account rolls record that £1 was spent on his obit day between 1347 and 1536." However, if you allow two-word analogues, the OED also defines *death day* as "The anniversary of the day or date on which a person died" (sense 2).

Comment: Wow, that is a very obscure usage.  I've never heard it used, myself.  But if OED says so, then I am forced to concede that may be the answer.  Although, the word birthday is not generally used to refer to one's date of birth.

Comment: A little obscure, perhaps. Interestingly, though, this entry in the OED was updated a few years ago for the 3rd edition, and these are the only two definitions that are not marked as obsolete.

Comment: Sweet!  +1 for the research.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist The benefit of institutional access to the OED :)

Comment: Thanks - those are pretty good near equivalents. Maybe if people commemorated these days more often they'd eventually make it to single word status... Thanks...

Comment: Those unfamiliar with this definition would probably think it means the date of their obituary or funeral service, a few days after their death.

Answer (score 4):

In a word, no.

If we commemorated deaths by a regular annual remembrance then there might be such a word.  We only have the word *birthday* because we do commemorate births.  But the day we are born is not our birthday!  It is our date of birth, just like the other end of things is called our date of death.  Our first birthday occurs one year after our date of birth.

German has two single words: *Geburtsdatum* and *Sterbedatum*. But then, German is possibly the most agglutinative language on the planet.

Completely off-topic now...

My favorite long German word? [*Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän*](http://lettersfromgermany.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitan/).

Means a "Danube steamship company captain."  This is not, however the longest German word.  Some candidates are discussed [here](http://german.about.com/library/blwort_long.htm).

Comment: _Chemistry_ is the most agglutinative language on the planet.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, @EdwinAshworth, but I beg to gently differ.  Would you call "(6E,13E)-18-bromo-12-butyl-11-chloro-4,8-diethyl-5-hydroxy-15-methoxytricosa-6,13-dien-19-yne-3,9-dione" a word?  I find that a bit difficult to swallow.

Comment: So, the downvote is because....?  Please explain yourself, sir or madam.

Comment: Yes, but I'd also recommend not swallowing it without taking sound advice first. Where along this series do words cease?: tin, butadiene, particle-board, bi-iodide, 3-dimensional, (6E,13E)-18-bromo-12-butyl-11-chloro-4,8-diethyl-5-hydroxy-15-methoxytricosa-6,‌​13-dien-19-yne-3,9-dione? And why? And are 'Chemistry words' actually 'English'? (PS Perhaps the downvoter is anti-German.) (Or anti-steam.)

Comment: On a saner note, are Geburtsdatum / Sterbedatum used for birthday / anniversary of date of dying, date of birth / date of death, all four of these, or three of these?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've seen the words used in official forms for recording such things, my mother-in-law's death certificate, for example.  Also in genealogical research.  If I think of it I may ask my sister-in-law who lives in Germany.  My wife is too Americanized to remember if "sterbedatum" is used in everyday conversation.  BTW, I love how you got my little joke, there! :-)  And "birthday" in the sense of an annual celebration is actually "Geburtstag", whereas "Geburtsdatum" literally means "birthdate".

Comment: Thanks! Hm - good point about the commemorative aspect. I was definitely more interested in finding a word that had that aspect of annual remembrance to it... but i guess there isn't one really...

Comment: And nice german word!

Comment: On the subject of words: I've seen conflicting definitions even for such a basic and necessary term. I thought I'd cracked this problem by using 'lexeme' for 'unit of meaning at least one orthographic word in length' such as {box=boxes}, {particleboard/s = particle-board/s = particle board/s}, {ship of the desert} – but some people don't consider multi-orthographic-word strings as candidates for lexemes. In spite of the fact that Crystal invented the term and used it that way.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist I give you [floccinaucinihilipilification](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/floccinaucinihilipilification).

Comment: Yes, @ElliottFrisch, I remember having a discussion of that word back in my high school English class. The teacher asserted that the Eton debating team made the word up in order to defeat a rival school in a debate -- since they didn't know what the word meant, they couldn't effectively respond to being accused of it.

Comment: Also - is there no German word then like Sterbetag that might mean "deathday" like birthday (if there were such a word as "deathday" which maybe there ought to be)?

Comment: Believe it or not, @user72476, I've seen that word used, too.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist All words are made up by someone at sometime. I remember running into that particular word in Patrick O'Brian's novel Master and Commander.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Oh yes just found it in Harry Potter when Nearly-Headless Nick invites Harry, Ron, and Hermione to his 500th Deathday party on October 31, 1992.

Comment: Be sure to read Mark Twain's _The Awful German Language_. He was really amazed by the size of some German words. I lent my copy to my German teacher (a native Hamburger), and she said she was howling with laughter as she read it.

Comment: @user72746 Yes, German does have such a word: Todestag, and the date of death of important people is often celebrated in Germany. Germans even organize whole year-long celebrations for the Todesjahr (centennials of the year of death) of great composers.

Comment: Of course "Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän" is the exact same word as the English "Danube steamship transport company captain". It just so happens that English, another Germanic language, uses spaces in it (to make it *even longer*, so I'm not sure why people keep bringing up German at all, when it clearly saves space). More to the point perhaps, "Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftskapitän" is also *exactly as common* as its English equivalent. How about considering a word every single German actually uses hundreds of times in his life, like *eintausendneunhundertneunundneunzig*.

Comment: [cont'd] so anyway, the point is that *Sterbedatum* is the exact same compound as "death date", and *Geburtsdatum* the exact same compound as "birth date". Spaces are a red herring, that's just orthography, there are no spaces in speech. Writing "birth day" instead of "birthday", or "between" instead of "by twe on" doesn't make it any more or any less of a word. It changes nothing. It's still the exact same single unit.

Answer (score 4):

Well **Birthday** and **Deathday**. It's not an official word. But I don't see why not. You also say **deathbed** don't you? Yet I have never heard of **birthbed**. Though it is the same thing. Only you don't ever actually lie in your **birthbed**, your mother does, but she is not born in this bed. With **deathbed** you are the one lying there so it is more frequently used.

Comment: LOL!  But not birthbed!  Actually, a woman who is in the throes of childbirth used to be said to be in "childbed".

Comment: +1. **Deathday** was popularized by J. K. Rowling via Nicholas de Mimsy-Porpinton, aka [Nearly Headless Nick](http://goo.gl/iHg0jl). In *the Chamber of Secrets* novel, Nick invites Harry Potter and his friends and a whole slew of ghosts to his [500th Deathday Party](http://goo.gl/zylUwB), explaining that the day of death is celebrated by ghosts more commonly and thoroughly than the day of birth, because a ghost is defined by their death (and they can actually remember it). Deathday would probably be a more common term if it had not been omitted entirely from the film adaptation.

Comment: @PatrickM now why does it matter if JK Rowling used a word in her book? Yes it may be a bit more popular than if your questioner uses the word. But language is a living thing. What prevents us to just make up words. In this case it is even a compound word. So it should be ok - totally. In Germany it is what we do anyway. Just stick two existing words together, et voila you have a new word that has the combined meaning of the previous two words. No magic there, no reference needed. Just understanding of the previous two words required.

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting question. Of course, anyone can make up a word and of course language changes over times. All I was pointing out was that if the questioner wanted to chose a recognizable word that would be instantly and correctly understood by the widest audience (presumably the chief reason one would ask for advice here), it wouldn't hurt to choose one that had been printed in [77 million copies of a book across 72 languages](http://www.hypable.com/harry-potter/book-history/).

Comment: @PatrickM right, back to economics of scale and ROI =)

Answer (score 3):

The genealogical term for it is [DOD](http://genforum.genealogy.com/bechtel/messages/997.html).

Plus, I digged up some rare instances of [deathdate](http://books.google.fr/books?id=NyEhAQAAMAAJ&q=%22deathdates%22&dq=%22deathdates%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=hWZRU8mLJ8bKPdvHgZgD&redir_esc=y) scattered here and there on the Net.

Even though these aren't single word expressions, consider also [quietus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quietus) [date](http://www.waymarking.com/waymarks/WMHWT2_Bayless_Cemetery_near_Gateway_AR) and [demise date](http://www.oldandsold.com/articles11/virginia-homes-10.shtml).

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing that I can think of is **expiration date/day**.  Or you can say the day they expired.

Comment: You can just shorten that to "Expiration: xx/xx/xxxx" or "Expired: xx/xx/xxxx" where xx is the date of death.

Comment: Don't forget Cubert's "Happy Growth-scraping Day" on _Futurama_!

Comment: Just thought I'd add that if you include the birthday, just the two dates will be enough for people to know what they mean. `John Doe, Jan 1865 - April 1950`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is. It is known as their feast day. Catholics have celebrated the feast days of Saints for thousands of years. The same term (feast day) also refers to the anniversary date of the day anyone dies.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your last sentence?  Reference for feast days of saints are easy to find (e.g., http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/what-is-a-catholic-feast-day.html), but I did not find a reference for generalizing feast day to anyone.